# How to change the voices when using pyttsx3

Tags: python, windows, pyttsx3

I am trying to change the voice using the setProperty function, but it does not change. voices[1] is supposed to be Zira while voices[0] is supposed to be David

I tried with 0 first, I changed it to voices[1] in my .setProperty function but the output is still the same(David's Voice). How do I change the voices? Here is my code:

```
import pyttsx3
voice_engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = voice_engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[1].id)
voice_engine.setProperty('voices', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):
 voice_engine.say(audio)
 voice_engine.runAndWait()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
speak("Hello ")

Comment: Shouldn't that be `voice_engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)`?

Comment: oh my god I didn't notice it lmao wasted like 30 mins on this. Thanks